# How to apply app background color globally in React Navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Basically am new to react native. I have created react native application with two pages. Am trying to apply background color for app globally. Am using React Navigation version-5(V5). https://reactnavigation.org/ There were few other similar posts but solutions were suggested for React Navigation V4. Can some one provide inputs.

```
       function AppNavigator() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="LanguageSelection"
            headerMode="none"
            gestureEnabled="false"
            screenOptions={{
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'tomato'},
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="LanguageSelection" component={LanguageSelection} />
            <Stack.Screen name="CountrySelection" component={CountrySelection} />
/>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary color variable in your assets folder and call it anywhere you want after import from the assets if you changing the primary color in where used the color is changed